# 'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 3406 pos 12: '!debugNeedsPaint': is not true

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I would like to express my appreciation to whoever is reading this for taking your time to look at this question.
I am a high school student developer and currently taking an internship for cs. I have found a problem that, according to previous Stack Overflow questions, seems to stem from an issue in the official repository.

First, let me explain to you what my situation is:
I made a program that first renders a google maps layer and then iterates through data and populates the map with markers from said data.

The data looks like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
  {
    'id': '1',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 6.0,
    'latitude': 34.3245,
    'longitude': 120.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '2',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 2.3,
    'latitude': 38.3245,
    'longitude': -120.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '3',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 7.0,
    'latitude': 34.3245,
    'longitude': -155.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '4',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 6.5,
    'latitude': 33.3245,
    'longitude': 60.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '5',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 1.2,
    'latitude': 39.3245,
    'longitude': -20.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '6',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 2.0,
    'latitude': 24.3245,
    'longitude': -150.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '7',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 1.0,
    'latitude': 34.3245,
    'longitude': 120.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '8',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 1.9,
    'latitude': 19.288,
    'longitude': -155.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '9',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 5.1,
    'latitude': 19.003,
    'longitude': -67.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '10',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 2.0,
    'latitude': 19.3245,
    'longitude': -67.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '11',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 3.2,
    'latitude': 62.3245,
    'longitude': -150.2345
  },
  {
    'id': '12',
    'globalKey': GlobalKey(),
    'magnitude': 6.5,
    'latitude': 33.3245,
    'longitude': -116.2345
  }
];
```

I have a list of latitude and longitude pairs that I want to render on my map

The code for iterating through the data and rendering markers for each data entry was directly taken from a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrnA6vpTXik&t=595s and looks like this

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({super.key});
  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};

  CameraPosition _cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.422131, -122.084801),
    zoom: 14,
  );

  bool _isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _onBuildCompleted());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('USGS Earthquake Map')),
      body: _isLoaded
          ? GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.terrain,
        initialCameraPosition: _cameraPosition,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        markers: _markers.values.toSet(),
      )
          : ListView(
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            Transform.translate(
              offset: Offset(
                -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
                -MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2,
              ),
              child: RepaintBoundary(
                key: data[i]['globalKey'],
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onBuildCompleted() async {
    for (final markerData in data) {
      Marker marker = await _generateMarkersFromWidgets(markerData);
      _markers[marker.markerId.value] = marker;
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  Future<Marker> _generateMarkersFromWidgets(
      Map<String, dynamic> data,
  ) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = data['globalKey'].currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    return Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(data['id']),
      position: LatLng(data['latitude'], data['longitude']),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List(),),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Earthquake Magnitude ${data['magnitude']}'),
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, you can see how a circle avatar is being built with the latitude and longitude of each data entry

Here's the problem
If the data has 1 entry, 5 entries, all the way to 12 entries, Then the program runs as intended. If the data has 13 entries, 20 entries and more, then with exception to the app bar, nothing renders and I have the message:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 3406 pos 12: '!debugNeedsPaint': is not true.

Here is my full code in case you require it: https://gist.github.com/da4head/4edc0fd553ebc01e6f127517150d6cf7
I have the correct dependencies and correctly set up the project according to the steps of the google maps flutter package.
If you have any idea in how this can be solved, please let me know